# How can I run code for a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, sleep

I want to play a sound (from a wav file) using winsound's `winsound.PlaySound` function. I know that `winsound.Beep` allows me to specify the time in milliseconds, but how can I implement that behavior with `winsound.PlaySound`?

I tried to use the `time.sleep` function, but that only delays the function, not specifies the amount of time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an expert with winsound, but perhaps call `winsound.PlaySound`, then a `time.sleep(n)` for however long you want, and then a `sys.exit(0)` or some other way of ending the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a thread to play the sound, start it. Create a thread that sleeps the right amount of time and has a handle to the first thread. Have the second thread terminate the first thread when the sleep is over.